# ios GPPShareBuilder "User must be signed in to use the native sharebox"

Tags: ios, api, google-plus, code-signing

I'm trying to share content with G+ API on my ios app.

this is the login:

```
GIDSignIn *signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.delegate = self;
signIn.uiDelegate = self;
signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
[signIn signIn];
```

after the login I call this function:

```
-(void) postGooglePlus
{
    id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];

    [shareBuilder open];
}
```

But I got this error:

```
[lvl=3] -[GPPNativeShareBuilderImpl open] User must be signed in to use the native sharebox.
```

I have setted Google+ API on developer console.

Why this error?

Comment: Have you got any solution to your question? If yes then please share here as I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Please suggest a solution

Comment: Any one have a solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: any update on this?